# What tag should be used when asking for a solution to a puzzle?

Tags: discussion, tags

Asking for a solution to a specific puzzle [seems to be on topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-it-on-topic-to-present-specific-logic-puzzles-or-brainteasers-as-questions), but what tag should we use?

[solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solutions) is already used for both these types of questions and questions discussing solutions in general.

Also, as per the comment by TheDoctor, there are two kinds of puzzles to solve:

1. Challenges set by a user to other users, and
2. Puzzles that users need help on.

We need to keep in mind that a tag should be as specific as possible (IMHO, [solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solutions) is way too general since on a stack about puzzles, there will be *a lot* of solutions) while at the same time being intuitive enough that a new user will pick the right tag for the question, instead of using an inappropriate one that just looked right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to score challenges](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17/how-to-score-challenges)

Answer (score 2):

[solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solutions) is, IMO, way too general of a tag. It should probably be split up into:

- [possible-solutions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possible-solutions): for questions like "How many solutions are there to _____?" or "What is the maximum number of solutions _____ can have?"
- [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution): for questions asking about a specific solution, like "How does this solution work?" or "How can this solution be proven?" (better tag name suggestion would be great)
- [solvability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solvability): for questions asking about whether a problem is solvable or not

Questions asking for solutions to puzzles don't need a specific tag, because that's just implied as it's the whole point of a *Puzzling* site. (If this tag is really needed, I'd suggest [specific-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-puzzle).)

Comment: In theory, most of our questions are going to be about specific puzzles, and a good portion will be about solutions. I'd avoid those two tags, and stick, with solvability and possible-solutions for solution counts.

Comment: I think "explain-solution" could work for your "solution" tag.

Answer (score 1):

For challenges, I propose [challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge), which should be obvious.

For puzzles where a user doesn't know the solution and posts it here in search of one, I propose either [solve-me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solve-me) or [solution-wanted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-wanted). Possibly one being a synonym of the other. That way, a new user posting a puzzle, will start typing `solu` or `solv` and see an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the [stance on riddles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/so-whats-our-actual-stance-on-riddles/57?noredirect=1#comment1182_57) question, we should have a [canonical-solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canonical-solution) tag, as opposed to [challenge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge). It means the question isn't a guessing game, where the answers seek "something that fits", but give the answer that is considered "officially correct" for given puzzle, citing sources - e.g. the a quote from the author, the jury from a competition where the riddle was presented, or a peer-reviewed paper.

This kind of answer doesn't leave room for doubts about correctness (even if it's incorrect, say, the author made a mistake solving own puzzle; it's still THE answer the author gave!) and while the solution may (always) arouse doubts, the answers can be rated by quality of the sources cited, quality of citations - accuracy as historical references.

Also, requests for solving riddles with this tag should be accepted (while general riddle questions remain strongly questionable).