# Riddles SE is a Proposal

Tags: discussion

It turns out that there is a Riddles.SE in the works.

How should this affect us? Should our recent discussions affect them?

Would it be amicable to Puzzlers if we were to fork Puzzling into Riddles & Non-Riddles?

I have noticed that a large percentage of recent activity here is Riddles... original creations and creative answers. I think this is an important thing to consider.

[HERE IS THE PROPOSAL.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64297/riddles) Follow if you want to see the Riddlers branch away...

However, I want to clarify that this is not what *I* want. *I like the community here*. And I feel that the contributors here are likely to be more professional than over there. Also, as stated in previous discussion on the matter, it's also possible that riddles *are* puzzles and thus that proposal is pointless.

Comment: Perhaps the 2 proposals should merge. Maybe we should be "Puzzles & Riddles" and have a puzzle tag and a riddle tag :P

Comment: that is something to consider.

Comment: Yes, it could actually help to improve the site in some ways.

Comment: @warspyking you probably recall my $Site1$ and $Site2$ commentary, it's really the same thing. We take the union but make it more explicit. I think splitting the community will fracture the community too much. And people who like one _normally_ like the other

Comment: Nope, don't recall, no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @warspyking http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/1466/2484

Comment: Interesting post. I +1 for "I will give all my rep to warspyking over a set of bounties and he will reign supreme!!!" Though I'm not sure if that'd be allowed, although I'm all for 8354 rep :D XD

Comment: d'alar'cop, what do YOU think we should do?

Comment: I left a post on their proposal telling them about what's happening here. Personally I feel they should integrate with us. (we can stay will Puzzling because riddles are puzzles imo). But it's up to the community really. It's all about pro or anti riddles as puzzles really.

Comment: Typo in an earlier comment, I meant 8454 rep.

Comment: Splitting would make it harder for both of us to get activity and make it out of beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Riddles proposal has received support because [riddles originally seemed to be off-topic](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/problem-with-duplicate-of-puzzling) for Puzzling.SE.  But based on the voting to the answers to [this meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/so-whats-our-actual-stance-on-riddles), the Puzzling.SE community appears to have decided that riddles are on-topic.

I think the Riddles proposal is going to face the same problems this community has faced with people thinking that riddles don't fit the SE format.  I think this community has done a good job recently of trying to improve riddle quality, by asking riddlers to make sure their riddles can have only one correct answer, and by asking people to fully explain how their answer completely solves the riddle.

So I think that proposal should be closed and they should join our community.

Answer (score 0):

**The proposal isn't going to get anywhere**. The proposal first has to define riddles, what is a riddle anyway? A rhyming riddle? A wordplay riddle? Then, they've got to prove it isn't a copy of Puzzling.SE. It isn't going to get far. :P

**Note:** Riddles aren't generally a good choice for the SE format anyway, answers are primarily opinion based, and answers can be way too broad. Riddles are usually of low quality, with little rules and guidelines included.

Comment: they seem to have very little attention so far as well... but still if all the riddlers here went there... they might have enough to get momentum

Comment: @d'alar'cop That or they'll crash and burn due to low quality. That's probably what'll happen since riddles are generally opinion based, and are very broad. :D

Comment: I think we need to be careful about the term "quality". "Quality" on SE means one thing... "Quality" to an artist means something else... I mean.. even interpretation of the most beautiful literature in the universe would be off-topic in SE because it's not not black and white enough... but you can;t tell me it's "low quality"

Comment: @d'alar'cop are you saying "What's greater than god but less than nothing" is not low quality?

Comment: no, but some riddles are pure gold... never read the Hobbit?

Comment: @d'alar'cop Nope I haven't.

Comment: then I'm afraid we must simply agree to disagree... and I must bounty all my rep to someone else :p

Comment: @d'alar'cop Wait! I can read it! Lol. But seriously, I know some riddles are freaking epic :P