# If riddles are on-topic, why did my questions get downvoted?

Tags: discussion

For example, [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5925/software-riddle-part-3) had 1 upvote before it got downvoted. Did I post too fast, titles, etc or are riddles not allowed?

Comment: There are many reasons to downvote, not just whether it's on topic or not. I can only assume some people didn't like it, thought it was too easy/hard, too ambiguous, etc. Voting is anonymous, and trying to find out why people vote the way they do is often an exercise in futility.

Comment: Note: I did downvote *this* question, because I don't feel having a bunch of people ask "why was I downvoted" on meta is useful.

Comment: @Geobits It's the recommendation of the establishment to do exactly that. It educates the community.

Comment: @d'alar'cop As far as I can tell, while commenting about downvotes is [encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/212780) (in *comments*), it's still [anonymous by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63895/212780), and asking why something was downvoted is often [seen as non-productive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115396/212780) even there. Bringing that same noise to meta is not useful, *in my opinion*, so I downvoted (as the tooltip says I should for something I see as non-useful). I certainly haven't seen anything explicitly saying that you should ask on meta. Link?

Comment: @Geobits http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/activate-power-mode#comment18700_5893

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riddles that follow the rules are totally allowed. While those rules are currently being formalized and will continue to change, [here's a good guideline for now.](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/46/5626) There are those on the site that feel we should only talk about puzzle theory. Some of them serial downvote puzzles themselves. Other times, it's that someone just doesn't like the style or feel that the quality is up to par. I've got a riddle that's over +50 right now, but it started off in the negatives. It's just part of the game. Don't get discouraged.

Comment: Right. Best to let it wash over you. Reputation points don't matter.

Comment: I wouldn't say "totally allowed." Good riddles with a single unique answer are allowed.

Comment: @Kevin Modified it to reflect your correct point.

Comment: your 'riddle over 50' is the highest-voted question on P.SE

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see the riddle and didn't vote on it, but I would guess it's been downvoted due to an apparent lack of effort. Riddles are very much welcome, low-quality **anythings** are not.

The lines don't rhyme, they have no meter (di-dah di-dah di-dah, di-dah di-dah di-dah) and personally I feel that it's a bit too obvious (**note**: I don't think overly-abstract riddles are good either - balance is important).

That said, don't let it dissuade you. Look at other riddles (maybe not from the last 2 days) and you'll see they flow when you read them. Try to copy that, and don't forget you can always post a riddle, give the answer (maybe in a spoiler tag) then specifically ask **How do I improve my riddle?** to get feedback from people who are more into riddling.

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse down-voting with voting-for-closure (or hold). While explanation for votes are *encouraged* it is not *obligatory* (but sensible voting is not yet *established* in the community as a whole).

Asking for the reasons of a down vote might be futile, as the person giving it most likely never reads your question (or cares about.)  Also, votes (up and down) change. If you receive *many* down votes, there is obviously something not quite right - or your puzzle/riddle has not yet found it's fan group.

Either way, if your posted puzzles/riddles are voted for [closure], then there is likely a "not suitable for this site" reason. If it is purely down voted, some / many people just don't think it's a good riddle. Opinions are free.