# Should we accept edits that only insert spoiler markup?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few edits in the suggested edit queue that consist pretty much entirely of people inserting spoiler markup for questions. I understand why it's desirable, but I'm wondering if the decision to mark something as a spoiler shouldn't just be left to the answerer themself.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, we don't have a solid consensus on whether answers should be in spoilers. There is some discussion on the topic [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/4), but it is clearly not definitive and shouldn't be taken as policy. Until and unless the site reaches a consensus that answers giving the solution to a chestnut / gem / puzzle should be in a spoiler, edits only or primarily to add such spoilers should be rejected as "too minor."

Comment: Agree 100%. Even if we *do* end up agreeing to use spoiler tags, edit the rest of the post! It's rare that nothing else can be improved.

Comment: Too minor? Nope, spoilers are *so much needed*!