# Spoiler tag in old Questions

Tags: discussion

Many a time I've seen that anonymous users edit an old question's (which are 2 or more years old) answer with a spoiler tag just for the sake of reputation. This not only give these questions unnecessary attention but also the new questions goes down in the list and hence they don't get the required attention. And getting reputation out of fixing very old question is "greed" as there is no need to do so.

I think moderators should do something in this regard.

Comment: If it's really anonymous users doing the edits (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/35758)), then they can't get any rep for it because they don't have accounts.

Comment: @Laurel what does that even means? I saw a number of questions which were like years old , have been answered but still someone edited its answer and applied a mere spoiler tag. :X.

Comment: Users without accounts can suggest edits which, if approved, will look as if "Community" (i.e. the robot moderator with only one rep) edited the post. In cases like that nobody gains any rep from the edit.

Comment: Do I have to specify the questions which were edited so that you can see that. And they are real time users with some rep. They aren't robos. @Laurel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can understand your concern about older questions getting edited and pushing newer questions off the front page. As for your other concern - users editing questions just for the rep - I don't see the problem at all.

When a low-rep user suggests an edit, it first has to be approved by higher-rep users, and if it is, the editor will earn a whopping **2** rep points. That's nothing. You'd earn five times more than that by posting an answer yourself and gaining a single upvote from it. And once you have 2,000 rep, you earn the "edit questions and answers" privilege: your edits are approved automatically and you no longer earn rep for making them.

As for there being "no need" to make those edits - **I disagree.** [Community consensus appears to be](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5043/31839) that it's perfectly acceptable and encouraged to edit spoiler tags into older answers. We don't want people visiting older questions and having their enjoyment ruined because the answer is right there in the open. We **certainly** don't want new users seeing those answers, thinking it's okay not to use spoiler tags, and then engaging in whataboutism when we ask them to use them. The spoiler tag rule needs to be applied consistently - no grandfather clauses.

In summary:

1. There are *much* more efficient ways for "greedy" users to earn rep than editing answers *en masse*;
2. Editing spoiler tags into answers, irrespective of age, has been site policy for quite some time;
3. Old answers need to be held to the same quality standards as new answers

Again, I understand your concern about new questions getting pushed down the front page. But your other concerns seem unfounded to me.

Comment: Sure thing!.....